# KnockoutJS Virtual element

Tags: knockout.js, virtual

What is the benefits of the Virtual Element described on this [page](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html) of Knockout? How a Virtual Element is different from regular HTML element and where it is being used?

Comment: In the virtual element context, this is important to know: The documentation still fails to note that the virtual element binding should not be used inside `<select>` elements to generate options because IE strips out all comments in a `<select>` long before KO has a chance to access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html#note-using-if-without-a-container-element

> In this case, you can’t put if on the `<ul>` (because then it would
>   affect the first `<li>` too), and you can’t put any other container
>   around the second `<li>` (because HTML doesn’t allow extra containers
>   within `<ul>`s).